# syntax error not sure what its saying or how to fix it

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script for school that searches your entire home directory for all files with the .java extension. For each such file, list the number of lines in the file along with its location (that is, its full path).

my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
for currfile in $(find ~ -name "*.java" -print)
do
    total=$[total+($(wc -l $currfile| awk '{print $1}'))]
    echo -n 'total=' $total
    echo -e -n '\r'
done
echo 'total=' $total
```

when i run it from the konsole i get error

```
./fileQuest.sh: line 5: total+(): syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")")
```

I am a novice and cannot figure out what the error is telling me. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total+()
```

This is the expression that's being evaluated inside of `$[...]`. Notice that the parentheses are empty. There should be a number there. It indicates that the `$(wc | awk)` bit is yielding an empty string.

```
total=$[total+($(wc -l $currfile| awk '{print $1}'))]
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If that part is blank then you get:

```
total=$[total+()]
```

---

Note that `wc` can handle multiple file names natively. You don't need to write your own loop. You could use `find -exec` to call it directly instead.

```
find ~ -name "*.java" -exec wc {} +
```